# How to deactivate feature when creating My Site

Tags: 2013, my-site, feature-stapling

I have activated the self service creation for My Site Web Application. 
The thing is that in SharePoint 2013 there is a feature named Minimal Download Strategy (Web Scope) that is activated by default when a new my site is created.

How can I deactivate the feature while the My site is being created. My first approach was to create a feature in the stapler that in FeatureActivated deactivate MDS feature but I think my custom feature is activated before MDS

Any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finnaly created a Self-Destruction WebPart. When is provisioned on mysite in the page_load I deactivate de MDS feature and the remove itself from the webpart catalog.